# Why isn't the panel painted?

Tags: java, swing, colors, java-2d, paintcomponent

**CODE**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class tester {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     JFrame fr = new JFrame();
     JPanel p = new JPanel();
     p.setBackground(Color.RED);
     p.paintImmediately(20,20,500,500);  
     fr.add(p);
     fr.setVisible(true);
     fr.setSize(2000,2000);
  }
}
```

I get a panel painted completely red. Why don't I get the line? How can I get it?

Comment: what line? Eventually got your intention from @aioobe 's answer :-) BTW, while reading the tutorial as suggested, please don't skip the chapter on java naming conventions, learn them and stick to them

Answer (score 8):

> ***I get a panel painted completely of red color.***

That's because you set the background and didn't do any further painting...

> ***Why dont i get the line ? How can i get it?***

This is not the way to do it. Why do you call `paintImmediately`? Here is what the documentation says:

> Paints the specified region in this component and all of its
>   descendants that overlap the region, immediately.
>
> It's **rarely necessary to call this method**. In most cases it's more
>   efficient to call repaint, which defers the actual painting and can
>   collapse redundant requests into a single paint call. This method is
>   useful if one needs to update the display while the current event is
>   being dispatched.

I suggest you read up on painting in AWT/Swing.

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

---

To get something like this

[image]

you could change your code like this:

```
JFrame fr = new JFrame();
JPanel p = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(20, 20, 500, 500);
    }
};
p.setBackground(Color.RED);
fr.add(p);
fr.setVisible(true);
fr.setSize(200, 200);
```

Comment: @ aioobe thank you. Actually i want to keep everything same and just add a line.That is the reason i was thinking of not calling repaint/paint again.Is there a way i can draw lines by not calling the paint method again but just add a line over what has been painted by the paint method

Comment: No, you can't call `g.drawLine` and expect it to stay on the panel for ever. That's not how it works. (Then you would have to paint the line on some buffered image, and paint the image to the panel.) You can't keep your code the same, and just add a "paint line". The code I provided is the solution that is closest to your code.

Comment: @ aioobe @ grassPro It can be done by setting up a condition in paint method.Paint method works for `if` till the OP wants and works for `else` when OP wants. `paint(Gra g) { if(firstTime) {//...} else {//...} }`

Comment: that's a Bad Idea, since the first time the component is painted, it may be far smaller than when you actually set it's size, pack it, maximize the window, you name it... and then the provided `Graphics` object will have a nasty clip set...

Comment: @ aioobe Yes that _could_ be a bad idea , but what does 'nasty clip set' mean ?

Comment: Try your method: Paint a line from `0, 0` to `100, 100` in a `50x50` window.. And then resize the window to see the full line...